# What is the meaning of "The Molecular Basis of Disease"

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, homework, pathology, terminology

What is the exact meaning of *The Molecular Basis of Disease*? I have one assignment which involves presenting Molecular Basis of a Disease. I am not really sure what points to add.

Comment: It means 'what is happening at molecular level' to result into the concerned diseased state. If you add the disease you are interested in, the question might be answered otherwise it is too broad to answer(though it has received one).

Answer (score 2):

There is an ELSEVIER research journal by the name of **BBA Molecular Basis of Disease** ([link to journal](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/bba-molecular-basis-of-disease/)). I think their synopsis of what the journal is about will illuminate what is meant by *The Molecular Basis of Disease*.

> BBA Molecular Basis of Disease addresses the **biochemistry** and
>   **molecular genetics** of disease processes and models of human disease.
>   This journal covers aspects of aging, cancer, metabolic-,
>   neurological-, and immunological-based disease. Manuscripts focused on
>   using animal models to elucidate biochemical and mechanistic insight
>   in each of these conditions, are particularly encouraged.

The keywords here are **biochemistry** and **molecular genetics**, so I would think of what kind of mutations, at what chromosomal locations can cause genetic disorders for example. Or in terms of biochemistry, what kind of biochemical environment can lead to alcoholic liver disease etc.